# hide results that echo in if conditional

Tags: scripting, output, telnet

I have the next script:

```
host=$1
port=23
user= <user>
pass="<pass>"
cmd1='show int descrip | i TRUNK|BBONE'
#cmd2=exit

( echo open ${host}
sleep 1
echo ${user}
sleep 1
echo ${pass}
sleep 1
echo "terminal length 0"
sleep 1

echo  ${cmd1}

sleep 1
#echo ${cmd2}
#sleep 1
echo "terminal length 24"
   sleep 1
echo "          "
) | telnet
```

This works, but I don't want that in the console appear all the comands and results, only execute.